# Should I follow up on a web application?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, applications, email

so I am a sophomore computer science major who has recently been applying to a lot of internships through web applications. While I have received a few responses, a lot of companies never got back to me.

Should I send an email to follow up? Is there a certain amount of days you should wait before "calling back"?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: That being said, recruiting processes take their time, I would wait at least a week before asking them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While I have received a few responses, a lot of companies never got
>   back to me.
>
> Should I send an email to follow up? Is there a certain amount of days
>   you should wait before "calling back"?

While unfortunate, it's fairly normal for companies not to respond unless they are interested. The better ones at least acknowledge receipt of your application - even if it's just an automated form response.

It's likely unnecessary, but you can follow up if you prefer. Always wait at least one week. Don't follow up repeatedly - that would just be nagging.